# Managed bean property becomes null in a different request

Tags: jsf

I am facing a problem when initializing a List with `new ArrayList<E>()`. This is my class:-

```
@ManagedBean(name = "clientBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ClientBean {

    public String msg = "", input, pendingMsg = "", user = "";
    public GossipClient client;
    public boolean inputDisabled = true, sendBtnDisabled = true, startBtnDisabled = false;
    String key = null;
    public List<ClientBeanDto> dtos;
    ClientBeanDto dto;
    String style;
    public List<OnlineList> onlineList;
    OnlineList userInfo;
    OnlineList newUser = null;

    public void start() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        client = new GossipClient(this);
        if (user != null && user != "" && client.connect()) {
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D://key.txt"));
                key = reader.readLine();
                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            client.start();
            inputDisabled = sendBtnDisabled = false;
            startBtnDisabled = true;
            msg = pendingMsg = "";
            pendingMsg = user + ", you are connected!";
            client.sendNick(key + user);
            onlineList = new ArrayList<OnlineList>();
            dtos = new ArrayList<ClientBeanDto>();
        }
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

The problem is with `public List<OnlineList> onlineList`. In `start()` method when the line `onlineList = new ArrayList<OnlineList>();` is executed, in debugging mode I find its value null whereas a similar object `dtos` in the very next line gets initialized and assigned a id successfully.
I can't seem to find any reason for this behavior and I am not getting any error/exception. Any wisdom will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** Found out that the `list` is becoming null whenever a button of xhtml (which the bean is backing) is clicked. I cannot find the reason though. The bean is SessionScoped and the other list(`dtos`) object is retained.

Comment: `user != ""` is always true. Use `!user.equals("")` or `!user.isEmpty()` instead

Comment: @Bohemian I am initializing `user = ""`; also, this is just a first draft, I am only considering the expected user-action's functionality, will handle finer details later; this is not the problem here

Comment: You're relying on string interning, which will work but won't work as expected if you pass in a blank from somewhere else. Don't initialize user and remove that test